# Commutators of the Lagrange-Laplace Transform with spatial derivatives

Tags: partial-differential-equations, linear-transformations, operator-theory, laplace-transform

To analyse fluid motions, we seek expressions for the commutator of the
Lagrange-Laplace transform and various spatial differential operators.

For a function $f(\mathbf{r},t)$ of space and time, we define two distinct Laplace transforms.
The *Euler-Laplace transform* (ELT) is evaluated at a fixed point in space
\begin{equation}
\widehat{f}(\mathbf{r}_0,s) \equiv {\cal L}[f](\mathbf{r}_0,s)  = \int_{0\ {\cal C}_0}^\infty e^{-st} f(\mathbf{r},t)\,\mathrm{d} t \,.
\label{eq:LT}
\end{equation}
Here, ${\cal C}_0$ is a line in the $\mathbf{r}$-$t$ space parallel to the time axis
and passing through the point $(\mathbf{r}_0,0)$.

The *Lagrange-Laplace transform* (LLT) is evaluated along a trajectory of the motion:
\begin{equation}
\widetilde{f}(\mathbf{r}_0,s) \equiv \mathfrak{L}[f](\mathbf{r}_0,s) = \int_{0\ {\cal C}_1}^\infty e^{-st} f(\mathbf{r}(t),t)\,\mathrm{d} t \,.
\label{eq:LL}
\end{equation}
Here, ${\cal C}_1$ is the trajectory of the motion starting at the
point $(\mathbf{r}_0,0)$.

**Non-commutativity of the LLT**

We aim to solve various approximate forms of the Navier-Stokes equations
governing fluid flow.  We consider the momentum equation in vector form,
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}\mathbf{V}}{\mathrm{d} t} + \mathbf{\mathbf{\nabla}}\Phi = \mathbf{0} \,.
$$
We define the Lagrange-Laplace Transform $\mathfrak{L}$ along the
trajectory $\mathcal{C}$ that passes through the initial point $\mathbf{r}_0$:
$$
\mathfrak{L} \left\lbrace \mathbf{V}\right\rbrace 
= \int_{0\, \mathcal{C}}^{\infty} \mathbf{V}\, \mathrm{e}^{-st}\mathrm{d} t \,.
$$

Applying $\mathfrak{L}$ to the momentum equation, we get
$$
\mathfrak{L}\left\lbrace \frac{\mathrm{d}\mathbf{V}}{\mathrm{d} t}\right\rbrace +
\mathfrak{L}\left\lbrace \mathbf{\mathbf{\nabla}}\Phi \right\rbrace = \mathbf{0} \,.
$$
We require an equation connecting the transformed variables.
The first term is $\mathfrak{L}\{\mathrm{d}\mathbf{V}/ \mathrm{d} t \} = s\widehat{\mathbf{V}}-\mathbf{V}(0)$.
In the second, we need to replace $\mathfrak{L}\left\lbrace \mathbf{\mathbf{\nabla}}\Phi \right\rbrace$
by
$\mathbf{\mathbf{\nabla}}\mathfrak{L}\left\lbrace \Phi \right\rbrace$.

The Euler-Laplace transform $\cal L$ commutes with spatial operators like $\partial_x$
and $\nabla^2$. This is not the case for the Lagrange-Laplace transform $\mathfrak{L}$. We write
$$
[ \mathfrak{L}, \mathbf{\nabla} ] \equiv \mathfrak{L}\mathbf{\nabla} - \mathbf{\nabla}\mathfrak{L} \,.
$$
and, to replace $\mathfrak{L}\mathbf{\nabla}$ by $\mathbf{\nabla}\mathfrak{L}$, we require an expression
for the commutator. Can quantities like $[ \mathfrak{L}, \mathbf{\nabla} ]$ and $[ \mathfrak{L}, \nabla^2 ]$  be expressed in analytical form?